# How often is supposed to change the schema of a table and how to deal with this?

Tags: database, schema, etl, amazon-redshift

We are using Redshift at my workplace, and in the last week I have been running through a serie of requests about changing the schema of a certain table, which have become a very tedious process (involving update of ETL jobs and Redshift views) every day.

The process can be summarized to:

1. Change the ETL job that produces the raw data before loading it to Redshift
2. Modify temporarily a Redshift view that uses the underlying table to allow modifications on such table.
3. Modify the table (e.g. add/change/remove column(s))
4. Modify the view back to use the updated table.

Of course, in the process there's testing involved and other time-consuming steps.

How often is it "natural" for a table schema to change? What are the best practices to deal with this without losing too much time or having to do all the "mechanic" process all over again?

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is having a **fixed schedule**, e.g. (1) you can submit change requests until Monday 10 AM, (2) all the gathered CRs are implemented until 4 PM, (3) new changes are applied next Monday.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons that data warehouse automation tools exist. We know that users will change their mind when they see the warehouse, or as business requirements change. Automating the process means that everything you asked for could be delivered in a few clicks of a mouse.

You'll find a list of all the data warehouse automation products we know, on our web site, at http://ajilius.com/competitors/